# Delphi XE2 - Building 64bit applications

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe2

I know you are supposed to be able to build x64 apps in Delphi XE2...

I am using a paid version, the starter version.

[image]

I checked in options as well and it will not let me change to 64 bit. Only 32.
I am also running XE2 from a 64 bit machine.

Could it be because I have the starter version? If so that is kind of ridiculous, see as I paid over $200 for this software.

Comment: You should have another entry in the Project Manager tree for 1Target Platform`. If you don't see it, you should check the feature matrix to see if other targets are included. (And for $200, you shouldn't set expectations too high; you're paying for a minimal version, and you should have checked to see what was included in that version before spending your money.) I don't complain when my $25K Hyundai is lacking some of the features of the Audi A4 my neighbor drives, because I choose to drive a lesser vehicle. You have the same choice when you decide what versions of a development IDE to buy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the [Feature Matrix](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/delphi-feature-matrix).  The 64-bit compiler, OSX compiler, and FireMonkey framework are not available in the Starter edition.